# “Android library projects cannot be launched”? But how about exploring APK?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Now I am totally confused by this error message: Android library projects cannot be launched.

I know how to disable the "In library" but my app needs the library, if i uncheck the "in library". I will have many errors in my apps
So how i can explore my apk with library
Thanks

Comment: post your build.gradle files please

Comment: "Android library projects cannot be launched" -- you are attempting to run a library project. You cannot run a library project, because it is not an app. You can run an app. You need to create an app that uses this library, then run that app.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare
firegloves: where i can find it please?

Comment: CommonsWare : as i mean. i have a game app but its linked to a library